# add items a list component, when scrolling. codenameone

Tags: list, pagination, codenameone

![enter image description here][1]i need know: how to add some items when i scroll until to the end of list component. like a pagination.i try to find on internet how to solve that, but i found an example just for a Form component and doesn't work , the list does not generate events on the end of her.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D53tL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are models so you can fetch data dynamically in said model, you can see an example of that in the [CloudListModel](https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/cloud/CloudListModel.java) class.

As well as a simpler version (used for the image swipe) in the [new workshop tutorial](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one-on-youtube) where we fetch images dynamically into the list model.

Alternatively you can just use containers where we have some support for [something like this](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/till-the-end-of-the-form).